# Any Windows XP software can tether my PC to iPhone?

Tags: windows-xp, iphone, administrator, tethering

I don't have admin access rights on one of the notebook, so I could not install iTune.
However the tethering features is really good, it allows me to browse internet via my iphone, while there's no WIFI.

Any software could do the same tethering via iPhone, but not requires an admin right to install? The OS is windows xp.

Comment: Have you asked whoever has admin rights to the computer to install it for you?

Comment: well... let's say it's not possible?

Comment: You are probably correct in your assumption.

Comment: i mean it's impossible to ask the admin's help. but i still prefer to find a work-around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a jailbroken iPhone there are a number of iPhone apps that can do WiFi or bluetooth tethering which does not require any special software on your computer. TetherMe, PdaNet, and MyWi all can do this, but if you do want usb tethering they do require software installation on your computer.

Comment: if it's not jailbroken?

Comment: iOS should have a built-in hotspot feature that you could utilize given that your carrier does not restrict usage. What version of iPhone do you have and what version of iOS are you using?